# Webpack: supporting less and scss files

Tags: webpack, sass, less, webpack-hmr, sass-loader

I'm trying to configure webpack to compile and distribute my app styles bundling them into one unique file.

My project structure (created with [this](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices))

[image]

My webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css');
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                '@angular/animations',
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/compiler',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/forms',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/router',
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'es6-shim',
                'es6-promise',
                'event-source-polyfill',
                'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
                'jquery',
                'zone.js',
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.less(\?|$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: extractStyles.extract('style-loader!css-loader!less-loader') },
            { test: /\.(scss|sass)(\?|$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: extractStyles.extract('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader') },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        extractStyles,
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    target: 'node',
    resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.less(\?|$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: extractStyles.extract('style-loader!css-loader!less-loader') },
            { test: /\.(scss|sass)(\?|$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: extractStyles.extract('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader') },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] }
        ]
    },
    entry: { vendor: ['aspnet-prerendering'] },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ]
});

return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

I've followed [this](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/README.md#example-a-simple-webpack-setup-that-builds-less), [this](https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/19/adding-sass-support-to-webpack/) and many other tutorials but web I run *webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js* seem webpack can't find or ignore my scss files inside styles folder.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.